# Transmitting infrared signals for LED strip (with a 44 key remote)

Tags: infrared

I probably have been looking for 6 hours at this point, so I figured to just ask it.

Does anyone know how to send an infrared signal that can be picked up by an LED strip with a regular 44 key RF remote.

I have mainly been looking for some kind of specification of these things and how they're generally made but cannot seem to find any, got no clue what frequency it requires and which signals to send (and in which encoding).

I've mainly been trying to transmit at 38000 frequency, also tried 40000 but neither worked, tried it with all sorts of patterns but I'm basically just looking for a needle in a haystack I feel like .

Comment: Is there a reason why this is tagged [android]?  If so, you should identify what hardware is on both sides, what libraries you are using and the Java/Kotlin code you are trying. You may want to look at our sister site https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=rf+signal for the general case.